# How can i make a relationship between a userUID and it's email in database of firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know how to do this and I need a little help whit it. This is my code in my loginpage. My central idea is to login a user with a username and not with an email, but I don't know how to do this.

Please help me

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  @ViewChild('email') email;
  @ViewChild('password') password;

  shows: boolean=false;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private afauth:AngularFireAuth, 
              private firebaseauth: AngularFireAuth,
              private database: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }
  login() {
    this.firebaseauth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value)
  .then(data =>{
  console.log("Inicio de sesión completo!", this.firebaseauth.auth.currentUser);
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
})
.catch(error =>{
  this.shows = !this.shows
})
}

}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for this is to append a random domain at the end of your username during signup and login by adding this at the start of your signup / login button function

> this.example.email = this.example.user + '@example.com';

**Note: this is probably not the correct way to do it.**